# HTML form submit not working after being loaded with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

so I am loading a portion of a page using jquery/ajax.

On the page the user sees, there is a "menu" where they select the date of the signup form they want to see.  All the forms are hosted on another page, each one inside a `div` id'd with the respective date of the form.  When the user clicks and item on the menu, there is an ajax call that displays the correct form on the user's page, pulling it from the other page by it's parent `div` and `id`.

The plugin I am using for the signup forms (it is a Wordpress site) has the page reload when you click Sign up, which then takes you to a form to fill out.  I have it so that the user's page does not reload, but via ajax shows the form.  This all works great - the only problem now is when the user clicks to submit the form.  This should be a normal form submit not using ajax, as I am not sure how to modify the plugin code to utilize it.  For some reason, the form is never actually submitted although the user's page does reload.

*NOTE: I am currently using the same exact signup form for each date, but once it is functional it will be a different signup form for each. This should not effect any functionality.

link to page user sees: summitsharks.net/volunteer-signup-page
link to page forms are hosted on: summitsharks.net/formhost

jquery/ajax code:

```
;(function($){
var ahref1;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.entry-content li a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ahref1 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#formloader').load('/formhost ' + ahref1);
    return false;
  });
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.entry-content #formloader a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ahref2 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#formloader').load(ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1);
    return false;
  });
});
})(jQuery);
```

PHP code of file that (I think) handles form submit:

http://pastebin.com/PeXB4Afi

I am looking for a solution that successfully signs the user up.  If somebody knows how to alter the plugin code to accept ajax submission, or normal submission that actually works, either one is perfectly fine with me.

Thanks a lot for looking through and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: is `#formloader` an iframe?

Comment: @JRulle My bad, should have specified that `#frameloader` is an empty `div`. That's where the other page's content is loaded into.

Comment: In the browser debug (F12, control-shift-I), do you see the form submission POST request being sent with the proper data?  It could also be a 
[wp nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) issue..

Comment: Try removing `e.preventDefault();` from your jQuery.

Comment: @Kenney, I believe I see the form data being sent. In chrome's developer console, if i got to network>documents>select my page>headers and scroll down, I can see all of the fields filled in, including the wp nonce field.

Comment: @Lal, Just tried this.  I thought preventDefault(); simply hid the fragment from the URL? It unfortunately did not fix the issue but the fragment is still being hidden...curious

Comment: Allright. You're fetching multiple forms, so it appears the `wp_nonce` gets overwritten in in PHP by the last form you requested.. Can you somehow get access to the error messages that the plugin generates? I.e. the server response after form submission should show an error... (unless WP's GET redirect after a POST is obscuring it..)

Comment: @Kenney hm..that does make sense, so then it fails the nonce check and therefore the form is never processed.  Is there any way to fix this? Would the easiest way just to be moving my forms from /formhost all onto separate pages?

Comment: Lots of ways to go. You could fetch the form again when the user selects it to make sure it's the last one - that seems easiest. But I'd add some debugging to the plugin to trace it's steps and where it bails. A simple logging like `file_put_contents( "/tmp/test.log", "something", FILE_APPEND);` (yeah i know.. WP ;-))

Comment: @Kenney Just saw your edit to the last comment, THe error messages are hidden because the page reloads on clicking submit button, so the ajax "de-loads" and that portion of the page where it would show isn't there anymore.  Just tested filling out the form on the formhost page itself, it fills in totally fine and successfully processes.  So the issue is bringing it into this other page - how would i go about re-fetching the form? I'm really very limited on my php knowledge at this point

Comment: Well, I'm not sure anymore if that's the problem.. It does look like the user clicks something to select one of the forms, at which point it is loaded, and so it already is the last one. I assumed you fetched all forms first, put them in divs and merely showed them. If this is the problem then choosing and submitting the last/bottom form would work. Does it?

Comment: @Kenney Currently since I am testing I actually have the same exact form in each unique div - if you go to the formhost link i gave above [link](http://summitsharks.net/formhost) you can see they are all the same form, and all change "interfaces" together since it is literally the same exact form being shown.

Comment: I checked your site, and I think I know what the problem is: you're posting to volunteer_signup_page (or `action=""` in the form), rather than posting to the direct form page (for example `/formhost/?sheet_id=1&task_id=1&date=2016-06-30`.

Comment: @Kenney Hm ok - is that a simple PHP fix? Somewhere in the code, where it generates the html, there must be an `action=""` that can be changed to generate the same url as the other links in the form, right?

Comment: I'd do it using jQuery: `$("#formloader form").attr("action", ahref1)`.

Comment: @Kenney I tried the following code: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#formloader form").attr("action", ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1);
});` since `ahref1` represents the `div` and `ahref2` represents the actual url generated by the plugin.  For some reason, in the page's source the action just literally looks like "`action`", no equals sign even or anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84620/discussion-between-user4843550-and-kenney).

Comment: I'd put that `function` as a callback in 
`$('#formloader').load('/formhost ' + ahref1, function(){ ... } );` so that it is set when a form is completely loaded, and inspect the "action" attribute in the HTML/DOM panel, and what is sent in the Net panel.
 
For some reason the `_wp_http_referer` POST variable is already correct, and WP code is usually consistent in using $_POST, so it may be something else entirely. If fixing the "action" form attribute doesn't fix this, I'm afraid you're going to have to resort to logging to find out where form processing is aborted..

Comment: Oh, and perhaps trying @JRulle's suggestion (use an iframe instead of a div), if you haven't already - that would fix the action attribute too.

Comment: @Kenney Perfect! If you'd like to post that as an answer I would accept, or if you'd let me post I will post my revised code.  One final thing, now that that is working, when I try to have an on click event for the submit button so that it doesn't pull me to the formhost page, it no longer submits.  Is there any way of staying on the same page after submitting the form?

Comment: There is; you could use an iframe or use jquery/ajax to submit the form. Then you'd have an AJAX form wrapper ;-)
This page need some cleaning up, comment/chat wise too; I'll check into that tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is expected to be posted from it's original URL, including the HTTP GET parameters `?sheet_id=1&task_id=1&date=2016-06-30`. Updating the form's `action` attribute to make it post to the proper URL can be done by changing

```
$('#formloader').load(ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1);
```

to

```
$('#formloader').load(ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1, function() {
  $('#formloader form').attr("action", ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1 );
});
```

However, using AJAX to post the form, this can be skipped:

```
var ahref = $(this).attr('href') + ' ' + ahref1;
$('#formloader').load( ahref, function() {
  $("#formloader form").on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      url: ahref,
      type: 'POST',
      data: $.param( formdata( $(this) ) ),
      success:function(data,status,jqXHR) { $("#formloader").html( data ) }
    });
    return false;
  })
})
```

The utility method `formdata` (see code snippet below) converts jQuery's [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) result to a proper hash.

In the working example below, I've moved the installation of form click handlers into the `.load` completion handler, rather than relying on jQuery to fire a second document ready event after injecting the form.

```js
;jQuery(function($) {

  $('.entry-content li a').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
    var ahref1 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#formloader').load( "/formhost " + ahref1, function() {

      $('.entry-content #formloader a').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ahref = $(this).attr('href') + ' ' + ahref1;
        $('#formloader').load( ahref, function() {
          $("#formloader form").on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax( {
              url: ahref,
              type: 'POST',
              data: $.param( formdata( $(this) ) ),
              success:function(data,status,jqXHR) { $("#formloader").html( data ) }
            });
            return false;
          })
        });
        return false;
      });

    });
    return false;
  });

});

function formdata(form) {
  var data = {};
  for ( var i in d = form.serializeArray() )
    data[d[i].name] = d[i].value;
  return data;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

UPDATE: Here is a code snippet that can be pasted in the browser's Javascript console:

```js
$ = jQuery;
$('.menu-volunteermenu-container li a').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
  loadFormSelector($(this).attr('href'));
  return false;
});

$('#formloader').on('load', function(){console.log("FORMLOADER UPDATD")});

function loadFormSelector(ahref1)
{
  console.log("Loading form selector");
  $('#formloader').load('/formhost ' + ahref1, function ()
  {
    console.log('form selector loaded');
    $('.entry-content #formloader a').off('click').on('click', function (e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      loadForm(ahref1, $(this).attr('href') );
      return false;
    });
  });
}
function loadForm(ahref1, ahref2)
{
  var ahref = ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1;
  console.log('Loading form', ahref);
  $('#formloader').load(ahref, function () {
    console.log('form loaded', arguments);
    $('#formloader form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        url: ahref,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $.param(formdata($(this))),
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
          $('#formloader').html( $(data).find( ahref1 ) )
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
    $('#formloader a').on('click', function () {
      loadFormSelector(ahref1);
    });
    return false;
  });
}
function formdata(form) {
  var data = {
  };
  for (var i in d = form.serializeArray())
  data[d[i].name] = d[i].value;
  return data;
}
```

It is refactored to show the 2-layer approach more clearly.

Comment: Thank you again so much for your help, and for actually explaining it so I can learn. Unfortunately though it is not totally working, when the sign up button is clicked it loads the entire formhost page into I assume the div formloader, and according to my admin panel the signup isn't successful either :/

Comment: My bad - I removed one line too many from the snippet in my edits (the 'data: $.param(..' line was missing). Should work now!

Comment: Ok final question - the form actually returns html code, so loading `#formloader` on success with `data` is showing the entire page! I have tried without success to show a specific `div`.  Would `data` have to first be parsed through to pull the right `div`, which would have the `id` of `ahref1`?

Comment: Update, I fixed this by replacing `data` with `$("#formloader").html( $(data).find(ahref1)` inside the success area.

Comment: I know I said last question...but now these lines which should work to prevent page reload when clicking "go back to signup form": `$('.entry-content #formloader a').off('click').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var ahref = $(this).attr('href') + ' ' + ahref1;
        $('#formloader').load( ahref, function() {`  do not seem to funciton whatsoever, as that link brings me to the formhost page, skipping loading it into formloader altogether.

Comment: I have temporarily fixed this by copy and pasting in `$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.entry-content #formloader a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var ahref2 = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#formloader').load(ahref2 + ' ' + ahref1);
    return false;
  });
});` at the end of the code, which had originally worked in the first place. It works now but probably not best option.

Comment: I added another snippet that you can paste in the browser; it should be more clear. However, the server-side code needs some modification, ideally. The use of `'/formhost + ' ' + '#july2'` is highly dubious: the loaded page (containing all forms) checks for it and displays only that div/form. Same with submitting: it signs one up for ALL dates. And when browsing the forms, it doesn't show the signup (it did earlier). Needs more work...

Comment: I'm actually not seeing that it signs me up for all dates - and I think the signup not showing might be more of an issues with WP Super Cache.